# HIghstock flags on first point is not rendered

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using HIghstock and I'm trying to put a flag in the first point defined in the series, but it is not being rendered. Elsewhere is working.

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pablorc/f9amsqms/) for all the info.

In the example I coded 4 flags, one on the first and second elements and other two for the same elements but in the axis, like this:

```
        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: data.slice(0,20),
            id: 'dataseries',
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 4
            }
        }, {
            type: 'flags',
            name: 'Flags on series',
            data: [{
                x: Date.UTC(2003, 8, 24),
                title: 'On first element'
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2003, 8, 25),
                title: 'On second element'
            }],
            onSeries: 'dataseries',
            shape: 'squarepin'
        }, {
            type: 'flags',
            name: 'Flags on axis',
            data: [{
                x: Date.UTC(2003, 8, 24),
                title: 'On first element and axis'
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2003, 8, 25),
                title: 'On second element and axis'
            }],
            shape: 'squarepin'
        }]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug?

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT:

Same example without using Date.UTC [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pablorc/t3j2anLk/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flags are not printed, when "point is on the border". Check the example: http://jsfiddle.net/t3j2anLk/2/ and try to scroll, until point from center will be on the left edge. The flag will disappear.

```
xAxis:{
        minRange:3600 * 1000
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The flag didn't show is because it can not get the right data.
(looks like there's some parsing issue [in source data](http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json) )

if you change `x: Date.UTC(2003, 8, 24)` to something else, it will work correctly.

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9amsqms/1/)

Comment: I don't think the problem is parsing issue. I recreate in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pablorc/t3j2anLk/) without using Date.UTC and the result is the same. (And I do need to put a flag in the first element :) )